# Need help to solve the seating plan

Tags: php

This is the php code I copied from a website but also there was technical mistake for which I was unable to find the solution.

```
// save selected seats in db

foreach($_POST as $vblname => $value) {
    $v = explode("-", $vblname);

    if ($v[1]) {
        mysql_query("UPDATE seats SET status=1 WHERE rowId='$v[0]' AND columnId=$v[1]");
    }
}
```

The error is `Notice: Undefined offset: 1`.

I found some error with explode and I searched everwhere but couldn't find a solution. Can you help?

Comment: `if($v[1])` will still send the E_NOTICE if the index is non existant. Use `if(isset($v[1]))`

Answer (score 1):

Undefined offset means you're referencing an array element that doesn't exist. So your `$v[1]` doesn't exist, likely because your `explode()` didn't find any hyphens to break the string up by.

Try this

```
foreach($_POST as $vblname => $value) {
    $v = explode("-", $vblname);

    if(isset($v[1])) {
        mysql_query("UPDATE seats SET status=1 WHERE rowId='$v[0]' AND columnId=$v[1]");
    }
}
```

Comment: What about other offsets? I'd do something like `if(isset($v[0], $v[1])) {`.

Comment: `$v[0]` will always be returned, tho, because [explode](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) always returns an array, even if nothing matches the delimiter.